# fill in the blanks quiz

Tags: jquery, html

In this quiz what i am doing is first click on the text box you want to enter text then click on the button whose value you want to put in box.
Problem- if i want to put the value abcdefghi in the box.
if i am clicking on first button and then on second button earlier content get erased.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body><button class="b"></button>
<button class="a">abc</button>
<button class="a">def</button>
<button class="a">ghi</button>

<div class="fill" id="f1"><input type="text" style="border:" value="">aaa</div>
<div class="fill" id="f2"><input type="text" value="">bbbb</div>
<div class="fill" id="f3"><input type="text" value="">ccc</div>


    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var activeFill;

   $('.fill input').on('click',function() {
activeFill = $(this); 
 });

   $('button').on('click',function() {
  if (activeFill !== 'undefined') {
   var val = $(this).html();
   $(activeFill).val(val);
   }
  });
    </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jza48Lt1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing contents every time, you have to append the content as shown below

```
$('button').on('click',function() {
  if (activeFill !== 'undefined') {
   var val = $(this).html();
   //$(activeFill).val(val); -- remove this
   // append content
    var prevContent = $(activeFill).val();
    $(activeFill).val(prevContent + val);
   }
  });
```

but above code will add duplicate values if you click same button twice, to prevent duplicate use below code

```
$('button').on('click',function() {
      if (activeFill !== 'undefined') {
       var val = $(this).html();
       //$(activeFill).val(val); -- remove this
       // append content
        var prevContent = $(activeFill).val();
        if(prevContent.indexOf(val)==-1) // if condition to check if text already present or not
           $(activeFill).val(prevContent + val);
       }
      });
```

**EDIT** - As OP want CLEAR and DELETE button functionality, see following code

HTML -

```
<button class="delete">DELETE</button>
<button class="clear">CLEAR</button>
```

jQuery

```
//variable to store last added text
var lastAddedText = '';

$('button.a').on('click',function() {
          if (activeFill !== 'undefined') {
           var lastAddedText = $(this).html();
           // append content
            var prevContent = $(activeFill).val();
            if(prevContent.indexOf(lastAddedText)==-1) // if condition to check if text already present or not
               $(activeFill).val(prevContent + lastAddedText);
           }
          });

$('button.delete').on('click',function() {
    var val = $(activeFill).val();
    val = val.substring(0,val.length-1);
    $(activeFill).val(val);
});

$('button.clear').on('click',function() {
    $(activeFill).val('');
});
```

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/2734/)**

Comment: thank you for your help but what if i want a delete button as well suppose the button with class b is delete button.

Comment: delete all text or just last entered text?

Comment: last index should be deleted.

Comment: sorry to bother u but i need 2 buttons one to clear and another to delete last written value.

Comment: delete button should work as a backspace button any ways thanks for ur help

Comment: thanks a lot it worked... kindly upvote my question so that i can ask another question

Comment: happy to help you :) .. If you are satisfied with answer please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple - you need to add previous value:

```
 $(activeFill).val($(activeFill).val() + val);
```